# Grunt vs Gulp vs Yeoman vs CodeKit

Tags: gruntjs, gulp, yeoman, codekit

I've purchased CodeKit a while ago, it makes front end projects really easy to setup.

The problem is, I'm in what I call a 'Front-end tool hell'

I've checked out Grunt and Yeoman a while back, and I don't see the point of using these tools if I'm using CodeKit. Am I missing a point?

Comment: may I recommend mimosa --> http://mimosa.io/

Answer (score 20):

Short answer: No. You don't miss anything

Longer answer: All of those tools (maybe with the exception of Yeoman) tackle the same thing, but from completely different directions.

*Codekit* is great to start, because it's like a Swiss army knife of tools, where you actually don't have to do that much work to get it going. Easy to configure and totally easy to use, especially if you don't have any command line experience.

If you want to have things more flexible and you need maybe more than the provided tasks (running a server, creating proxy connections, FTP uploads, having tools included which CodeKit misses); or if you simply need to integrate your builds in continuous integration environments, you will most likely end up with a command line build tool, and also most likely with *Grunt*. Grunt's biggest strength is in having multiple configurations for different environments. So if you want to have the same code compiled in different ways for different destinations, that works wonderfully with Grunt.
If Grunt can't offer you more than CodeKit, fine, stick with CodeKit!

Grunt has also its limitations, especially in terms of execution time and intermediate file results. That's because in Grunt you take a defined process and configure it. *Gulp* on the other hand allows you to define the process itself, thus making it even more flexible.

Oh, and concerning Yeoman: If you have a basic setup and like it, write a Yeoman generator and easily scaffold new ones by the push of a button. Or, if you are new to things like, let's say Angular, take a community generator and see what the pros think it's best for such an application. I'm not sure if CodeKit can do "project templates" by now, but that's the idea behind it.

Hope this helped.